# How to redirect pages with a common filename at the end of the URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to redirect different pages which end with the same expression, for example:

```
/something.php
```

I have the following URLs:

```
/truc/machin/something.php
/truc/tous-56/something.php
/truc/machin/tous-56/something.php
```

I don’t want to have tons of lines in my `.htaccess`, and I want to solve this through a common rule with regular expressions.

Could you please help me finding the right expression to use, in order to have just on line redirecting everything in my `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/something.php$ /somethingelse.php [R=301,L]
```

It will redirect `something.php` to `somethingelse.php` if `something.php` is in the url.